# flask multiprocessing every request

Tags: python, sockets, flask, multiprocessing, udp

I have two processes:

- **frame_collector**, this process collect JFIF frame from UDP socket and put it in `frame` queue.
- **flask_service**, this process is just normal web server that will display JPEG series aka MJPEG in index route (`/`), it also has `frame_consumer` that will get frame from queue that has been put from `frame_collector`

This is my code:

```
def frame_collector(frame): # process 1
  import io
  import socket
  SERV_IPV4, SERV_PORT = ('192.168.43.150', 8888)
  udpSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
  udpSock.bind((SERV_IPV4,SERV_PORT))
  isWriting = False
  while 1:
    dataRecv, CLNT_ADDR = udpSock.recvfrom(65507)
      
    if not isWriting:
      if dataRecv[:2] == b'\xff\xd8': # Start of JPEG
        isWriting = True
        buf = io.BytesIO()

    if isWriting:
      buf.write(dataRecv)
      if dataRecv[-2:] == b'\xff\xd9': # End of JPEG
        isWriting = False
        buf.seek(0)
        frame.put(buf.read())

def flask_service(frame): # process 2
  from flask import Flask, Response
  app = Flask(__name__)

  def frame_consumer():
    while 1: yield b'--frame\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame.get() + b'\r\n'

  @app.route('/mjpeg')
  def mjpeg():
    return Response(frame_consumer(),mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

  @app.route('/')
  def index():
    return """
    <body style="background: blue;">
      <div style="width: 800px; margin: 0px auto;">
        <img src="/mjpeg">
      </div>
    </body>
    """

  app.run(host='192.168.43.150', threaded=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
  from time import sleep

  frame = Queue()

  p1 = Process(target=frame_collector, args=(frame,))
  p2 = Process(target=flask_service, args=(frame,))

  p1.start()
  p2.start()
  while 1:
    try:
      sleep(5)
    except:
      break
  p1.terminate()
  p2.terminate()
  print('All processes terminated!')
```

When a client access (doing http request) my webserver, the MJPEG display smoothly 60FPS. The problem is, when many clients access it, my MJPEG start lagging. More clients more lagging, how do I handle this?

I suspect in `frame` variable which it's a Queue that shared between thread in `flask_service`.

**Update**:

Thanks for your try Booboo, I tested your code and this is what I got:
First error is `flask_service` error need argument, it's okay I fix it with remove parameter in `flask_service`.
Then your code is working fine the webserver is running. After it I tested access the `192.168.43.150:5000/mjpeg`. Yes it's working fine like what I did in my original code, but the problem come when another client access it at same time, I tested it with many clients. Here is the error said and that new client is stuck in loading while first client got 60FPS MJPEG.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\User\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\udp-wifi-camera\src\test_punya_orang.py", line 9, in frame_collector
    udpSock.bind((SERV_IPV4,SERV_PORT))
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
Ending up.
```

No wonder error was occured, your code was trying create new socket with new address when new client come while that socket (with same address) already created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** feel free to skip down to the third code example. But if you want an explanation as to how I arrived at it, then read the following:

Since I don't have access to your server, I have modified your program so that the `frame_collector` just writes sequential numbers 1, 2, 3 ... to the queue and I am using server-sent events (sse) to provide a stream of these numbers to `flask_service`:

```python
from time import sleep

def frame_collector(frame): # process 1
    n = 0
    while True:
        n += 1
        frame.put(f'data {n}')
        sleep(.5)

def flask_service(frame): # process 2
    from flask import Flask, Response

    app = Flask(__name__)

    def frame_consumer():
        while True:
            data = frame.get()
            msg = f'data: {data}\n\n'
            yield msg

    @app.route('/stream')
    def stream():
        return Response(frame_consumer(), mimetype='text/event-stream')

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return """<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Server-sent events demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
  </ul>

<script>
  try {
    let eventList = document.querySelector('ul');
    let evtSource = new EventSource('/stream');

    evtSource.onopen = function() {
      console.log("Connection to server opened.");
    };

    evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
      var newElement = document.createElement("li");
      newElement.textContent = e.data;
      eventList.appendChild(newElement);
    };

    evtSource.onerror = function() {
      console.log("EventSource is done?.");
      console.log('Closing connection ...');
      evtSource.close();
    };
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
"""

    app.run(threaded=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

    frame = Queue()

    p1 = Process(target=frame_collector, args=(frame,))
    p2 = Process(target=flask_service, args=(frame,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    while 1:
        try:
            sleep(5)
        except:
            break
    p1.terminate()
    p2.terminate()
    print('All processes terminated!')
```

If I start this up and go to http://127.0.0.1:5000/, I will see these numbers being added to a `<ul>` (user list). But if I then open up a second browser tab and go to http://127.0.0.1:5000/, you will see that each tab is printing only half of the generated numbers. In other words, you are correct that each client is getting frames (or numbers in this demo) from the same queue and that is the problem.

The solution is as follows:

First, see the documentation on [multiprocessing.Pipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pipe#multiprocessing.Pipe) and its related [`connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pipe#multiprocessing.connection.Connection) objects.

The main process creates an initially-empty [managed dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=dict#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.dict), which is sharable among processes, and passes this to the child processes `frame_collector` and `frame_service` as the *clients* argument. Every time the '/stream' route is invoked ('/mjpeg' in your case) a new `Pipe` instance is allocated and its sender `connection` is added to  the clients dictionary where the key is the connection's handle (an integer) and the value is the connection itself. When the `frame_collector` has assembled a complete frame, it broadcasts the frame to every connection in that managed clients dictionary. If an error occurs sending to a particular connection, that client's sender connection is deleted from the dictionary of clients. A managed dictionary is used since it makes the removal of such connections easier.

Needless to say, the more clients you have the more `connection.send` calls must be made for each frame. Performance will be determined by your CPU power, what the frame rate is and how many clients there are:

```py
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Pipe

def frame_collector(clients):
    n = 0
    try:
        while True:
            n += 1
            msg = f'data {n}'
            d = dict(clients) # Make copy into local dict
            for handle, sender in d.items():
                try:
                    sender.send(msg)
                except: # Client has gone away?
                    del clients[handle]
            sleep(1/60)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

def flask_service(clients):
    from flask import Flask, Response

    app = Flask(__name__)

    def frame_consumer():
        receiver, sender = Pipe(False)
        clients[sender._handle] = sender
        while True:
            data = receiver.recv()
            msg = f'data: {data}\n\n'
            yield msg

    @app.route('/stream')
    def stream():
        return Response(frame_consumer(), mimetype='text/event-stream')

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return """<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Server-sent events demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
  </ul>

<script>
  try {
    let eventList = document.querySelector('ul');
    let evtSource = new EventSource('/stream');

    evtSource.onopen = function() {
      console.log("Connection to server opened.");
    };

    evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
      var newElement = document.createElement("li");
      newElement.textContent = e.data;
      eventList.appendChild(newElement);
    };

    evtSource.onerror = function() {
      console.log("EventSource is done?.");
      console.log('Closing connection ...');
      evtSource.close();
    };
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
"""

    app.run(threaded=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

    with Manager() as manager:
        clients = manager.dict()

        p1 = Process(target=frame_collector, args=(clients,))
        p2 = Process(target=flask_service, args=(clients,))
        p1.start()
        p2.start()

        try:
            p2.join() # block while flask_service is running
        except: # ctrl-C
            p1.terminate()
            p2.terminate()
        finally:
            print('Ending up.')
```

**Your code should therefore look something like:**

```py
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Pipe

def frame_collector(clients):
  import io
  import socket
  SERV_IPV4, SERV_PORT = ('192.168.43.150', 8888)
  udpSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
  udpSock.bind((SERV_IPV4,SERV_PORT))
  isWriting = False
  try:
    while 1:
      dataRecv, CLNT_ADDR = udpSock.recvfrom(65507)

      if not isWriting:
        if dataRecv[:2] == b'\xff\xd8': # Start of JPEG
          isWriting = True
          buf = io.BytesIO()

      if isWriting:
        buf.write(dataRecv)
        if dataRecv[-2:] == b'\xff\xd9': # End of JPEG
          isWriting = False
          buf.seek(0)
          frame = buf.read()
          d = dict(clients) # Make copy into local dict
          for handle, sender in d.items():
            try:
              sender.send(frame)
            except: # Client has gone away?
              del clients[handle]
  except KeyboardInterrupt: # ctrl-C
    pass

def flask_service(clients): # process 2
  from flask import Flask, Response
  app = Flask(__name__)

  def frame_consumer():
    receiver, sender = Pipe(False)
    clients[sender._handle] = sender
    while True:
      yield b'--frame\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + receiver.recv() + b'\r\n'

  @app.route('/mjpeg')
  def mjpeg():
    return Response(frame_consumer(),mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

  @app.route('/')
  def index():
    return """
    <body style="background: blue;">
      <div style="width: 800px; margin: 0px auto;">
        <img src="/mjpeg">
      </div>
    </body>
    """

  app.run(host='192.168.43.150', threaded=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

  with Manager() as manager:
     clients = manager.dict()

     p1 = Process(target=frame_collector, args=(clients,))
     p2 = Process(target=flask_service, args=(clients,))
     p1.start()
     p2.start()

     try:
       p2.join() # block while flask_service is running
     except: # ctrl-C
       p1.terminate()
       p2.terminate()
     finally:
       print('Ending up.')
```

Comment: Thanks for your try, I updated my question, can you see it?

Comment: Based on error, I think UDP socket instance should have created once and that instance must be passing through parameter in `Process(target=frame_collector, args=(insert socket here))`

Comment: I have removed the erroneous *frame* argument to `flask_service`. I am not that familiar with UDP, but after doing some investigation I think the problem is because UDP is a connectionless protocol, each client must come in via a different address, which is not the case here. I don't see how you can create a single client socket instance and pass it to multiple child processes with each trying to receive data from it. I need to rethink this. I will get back to you.

Comment: There's no child processes, only two processes in my code, where UDP instance is not accessible in `flask_service`. That's why I'm using `Queue` to access data (frame).

Comment: `flask_service`  is a child process started by the main process and it then starts one or more `frame_collector` child processes of its own (one for each invocation of URL `/mjpeg`. Is it the word 'child' that bothers you?

Comment: okay sorry about it, but anyway I don't think so about cause why UDP connectionless, the problem is instance of ```socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)``` is created everytime new client request (creating new instance) while it should be **ONCE** because TCP is made from `socket.socket` too.

Comment: How can multiple `frame_collector` processes sharing a single socket (which is not even possible) each do `recvFrom` calls and expect to retrieve the same data? Moreover, your bigger problem is that a socket cannot be serialized with `pickle`, which is required to pass a `socket` instance to another process. So multiple processes cannot share a single socket and we now start instance of the the `frame_server` process. But if you are so sure of yourself, then try it!

Comment: `frame_collector` is just collecting incoming JPEG from another device like microcontroller camera through UDP socket. It doesn't proccess it, just collecting and put it in `Queue`. Then later, the `Queue` will consumption by `flask_service`. My idea is simple, I just want flask display incoming JPEG with high FPS which I already achieved it but only when 1 client connected, for many clients, it start lagging and I'm sure it's from flask who can't display same data at same time from stream data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247066/discussion-between-booboo-and-citra-dewi).

Comment: See updated solution. Please read and try to understand everything.

Comment: Thankyou soo much, this code is working fine, I still got 60 FPS in MJPEG streaming even though many client access it in their browser, this solved my problem. I knew it I should have use Pipelining instead of Queue.

Comment: This is resolved not just by switching from a Queue to a Pipe. The code had to be modified so that whenever the `frame_collector` re-constructed a new frame, it had to be broadcast to all the clients and so you need to create individual `Pipe` instances for each client. Make sure you understand this. Also, the real reason for using a `Pipe` in addition to achieving greater efficiency is that you cannot add a `Queue` instance to a managed dictionary.